# How to use qt-speech in Kubuntu 18.04 (cli / Okular)

Tags: 18.04, kde, qt, okular, text-to-speech

In Kubuntu 18.04 Okular can read any selection text, or the whole document by default.

That is great, it is using `qtspeech5` but

1. How do I set the language?
2. How can I use it from the CLI?

Can't find any setting in system-settings for speech.

Answer (score 2):

## Okular

As for now (also in 19.04) Okular rely on libflite1 which supports only English via  only one available qtspeech5-flite-plugin.

## CLI

- There is `jovie` and in tray you can configure it and select language. You can use it from command line like `qdbus org.kde.kttsd "/KSpeech" say "Hello World." 0`.

## Accessibility

- Another possibility is `orca` which is configured from: System Settings → Accessibility → Screen reader → Launch Orca Configurator.

## CLI with [Google's TTS](https://gtts.readthedocs.io) (online)

Install with `sudo apt install python-pip sox libsox-fmt-mp3`
and then `pip install gTTS`.

Usage: `~/.local/bin$ ./gtts-cli Hello\ World | play -t mp3 -`